# Windows 10 boot loop trouble while booting up

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have a problem with my Windows 10 while its booting up. When it is booting up, my computer reboots after about 10 seconds and it does so for 3 times again. Then the recovery screen appears and says that I should troubleshoot my windows 10. Even whenever I want to change my directory to my `C:/` partition, an error occurs that this drive is corrupted and its files aren't readable anymore and if I run the chkdsk, nothing changes. What should I do now? Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What does Event Viewer tell you?

Comment: My Windows 10 doesn't even boot up. How can I access Event Viewer?

Comment: You don't state in the question that you are never able to get into Windows. It sounds as though you end your description about midway through the problem and the steps you've taken so far. Also CHKDSK can only repair certain types of disk corruption, mainly by marking the portions of the disk so that Windows won't write to them. If critical data is in those bad parts, it won't recover it for you.